# A natural number can become equal to double of itself, zero, or any natural number in between. What is the probability of outcome X after n tries.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, decision-trees

Tentative title, too long to fit the titling rules: Let A be a natural number. An experiment is defined as A doubling in count, becoming zero, or becoming any natural number in between zero and 2A. Question: After n tries, what is the probability that A will be X, where X is any natural number between zero and 2A.

This is derived from a videogame, Path of Exile, where a gamble is presented to the player:

-In this game, there exists divination cards. Each individual card can be collected and stacked up to a certain maximum number, and upon reaching a full stack of cards they can be redeemed for a reward deleting the cards from the inventory of the player who gathered them.

-The player is presented with a gamble that he can repeat as many times as he wants as long as the number of cards to be gambled are equal or less than half the maximum numbers that can be collected in a stack, or half minus one for an odd maximum number of collected cards in said stack.

-For each time the player gambles, the number of cards on the stack can

*(1) double and become equal to the maximum number of cards possible for a stack or, in the case of an odd maximum numbers of cards in a stack, become equal to the maximum minus one card,

*(2) be lost (become zero, however the stack is no longer in the players inventory) or

*(3) the number of cards in the stack can become any natural number in between zero and the maximum of cards or, in the case of an odd maximum numbers of cards in a stack, become any natural number in between zero and the maximum of cards minus one.

Given that these cards are valuable for a player they may be tempted to gamble their cards in order to increase the total number of cards they ultimately own. In order to calculate the expected value of this gamble, first we must calculate the probability of each outcome given the initial number of cards offered in the gamble and how many times a gamble will happen.

---

### COMPLETED WORK SO FAR

In order to tackle this problem I have calculated the probability for an experiment that starts with only one card and where the gamble is attempted three times. To simplify this calculation, i have ommited the upper outcome limit for every gamble.

First Gamble:

The initial number of cards to be gambled is one. The possible outcomes is either 2, 1 or 0. Each one of these outcomes has equal weighting and the probability of each ocurring is one in three.

Second Gamble:

Would the first gamble had resulted in 2, the possible outcomes of the second gamble are 4, 3, 2, 1, 0. Each one of these outcomes has equal weighting and the probability of each ocurring is one in five.

Would the first gamble had resulted in a 1, the possible outcomes is either 2, 1 or 0. Each one of these outcomes has equal weighting and the probability of each ocurring is one in three.

Would the first gamble had resulted in a 0, the only possible outcome of the second gamble is 0, thus the experiment concludes.

Third gamble:

Would the first gamble had resulted in 2 and the second gamble had resulted in a 4, the possible outcomes of the third gamble are 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0. Each one of these outcomes has equal weighting and the probability of each ocurring is one in nine.

From this we can conclude a single outcome where the result of the experiment is 6. The probability that the first gamble had resulted in a 2, the second gamble had resulted in a 4 and the third gamble had resulted in a 6 is equal to the compound of the probability of each of the gambles independently. To say, the probability is 1/3 * 1/5 * 1/9.

After manually completing the probability tree, only two experiments concluded in a total number of 6 cards as the outcome:

*The first one corresponds to the experiment where the first gamble results in a two, the second results in a four, and the third results in a six. This outcome has a 1/3 * 1/5 * 1/9 chance of ocurring.

*The second one corresponds to the experiment where the first gamble results in a two, the second camble results in a three, and the third gamble results in a six. This outcome has a 1/3 * 1/5 * 1/7 chance of ocurring.

From this we conclude that the chance of the experiment resulting in a six is equal to the sum of these two experimental outcomes, aproximated to 1.69% chance of ocurring.

After calculating the probability of every outcome for the experiment, these are the probabilities of each outcome:

[image: Probability of obtaining X after gambling 1 card a total of 3 times]

The same method can be applied for any number of gambles and with any number of starting cards.

---

QUESTION:

Can this process be generalized?

At first glance, the probability of the experiment resulting in an outcome can be generalized as a sum of multiplications.

To say, for the experiment, the chance of outcome equals 1 is:

P(1) =   1/3 * 1/5 * 1/9
+ 1/3 * 1/5 * 1/7
+ 1/3 * 1/5 * 1/5
+ 1/3 * 1/5 * 1/3
+ 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/5
+ 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3 = 11.17%

the chance of outcome equals 3 is:

P(3) =   1/3 * 1/5 * 1/9
+ 1/3 * 1/5 * 1/7
+ 1/3 * 1/5 * 1/5
+ 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/5 = 5.25%

NOTES:

The probability of an experiment with outcome 1 is equal of that of an experiment with outcome 2. this happens because of the nature of the outcome of the first gamble having a maximum of equal to the double of the starting numberof cards making the maximum outcom always an even number.

[Excel worksheet with my completed work](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18piNIOA68NX7rwe8a4Uid0EhIn8QRi2_/view?usp=sharing)

This is how the gamble is presented inside of the game

[image: This is how the gamble is presented inside of the game]

Comment: The expected outcome of a gamble is the number of cards gambled.  So the net expected gain stays zero, no matter how often you gamble.  But the variance increases.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Starting with $n$ cards and betting all the cards $t$ times seems  gives an expectation of $n$ and a  variance of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \left(\left(\frac43\right)^t-1\right)$, equal to $1$ and $\frac{74}{27}$ when $n=1$ and $t=3$ as in your example

Comment: Is there a maximum number of cards?  If so, it's a finite problem.You may as well just write a program to calculate it.  Unless you really need the figures for an unlimited number of cards or want to torture yourself with calculations.  Even if I did that, I would also write the program to verify my answer as mistakes would be likely.

Comment: @badjohn - with an unlimited number of attempts, the probability of ending with zero cards approaches arbitrarily close to $1$, even though the expected number of cards remains constant and positive: another example of a probabilistic convergence curiosity

Comment: I might have not read carefully enough, I got the impression that there might be a limit on the game length.

Comment: @Henry (2) The question is about a generalization for the probability that an experiment where you start with _n_ cards and gamble _t_ times results in the outcome _x_. (1) You are right, the expected value is constant and equal to the number or cards initially gambled, however i'm interested on the probability distribution.

Comment: @badjohn Thanks! You're right in that it would be easier to write a program to calculate it, however my question is a precursor since i don't know the generalization of the probability for any outcome given any number of starting cards to gamble and any numbers of gamle attempted. You are also right in that there is a limit to the maximum number of cards that can result from the gamble, Ex: If i gamble half a stack and double it on the first gamble, the experiment ends (for even numbers), however to start to tackle this problem i simplified it and defined no maximum outcome.

Comment: Remember that I am not claiming to have studied it well.  I thought that the size of the pack might impose a limit though I know that the OP is also considering an unlimited version.  So, it really depends on what he wants.